# How to address initial conditions for coupled system in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, coupling

We have a coupled system of 10 ode each. The coupling presents in the last equation.

I thought about using a matrix 10 by 2 as initial conditions.I also followed a similar question with the same title here, but I still get the same errors ('Too many input arguments.')

```
time = [0 5];
x1_0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
x2_0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
initial = [x1_0;x2_0];
x = NaN(length(initial),2*length(time));

[t,x] = ode45(@ode,time,initial);


function [dxdt] = ode(x)

N = 2;

dxdt = NaN(10,2);

for i = 1:N
    dxdt(1,i) = x(6,i);
    dxdt(6,i) = (x(3,i)-x(4,i)+x(5,i)) - x(6,i) - x(1,i);
    dxdt(2,i) = x(7,i);
    dxdt(7,i) = (x(3,i)-x(4,i)+x(5,i)) - x(7,i) - x(2,i);
    dxdt(3,i) = x(8,i);
    dxdt(8,i) = (x(1,i)) - x(8,i) - x(3,i);
    dxdt(4,i) = x(9,i);
    dxdt(9,i) = (x(2,i)) - x(9,i) - x(4,i);
    dxdt(5,i) = x(10,i);
    if i == 1
        j = 2;
    elseif i == 2
        j = 1 ;
    end
    dxdt(10,i) = (x(3,j)-x(4,j)+x(5,j)) - x(10,i) - x(5,i);

end
end
```

If my mistake is the use of a matrix initial conditions instead of a vector, using a 1 by 20 vector, and adjust the ode form accordingly would be not practical, I think
- What would be another more efficient way to address the initial conditions 
-What is unnecessary from the inputs I have given and why?
-Is there any other computational way to represent the coupling?

EDIT: If I use the option: "function dxdt = ode(t,x)" the errors are the following:

```
Error in Test11>ode (line 33)
dxdt(10,i) = (x(3,j)-x(4,j)+x(5,j)) - x(10,i) - x(5,i);

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, 
varargin);

Error in Test11 (line 9)
[t,x] = ode45(@ode,time,initial);
```

If I change the way I call the function, so that: 
"[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x)ode(x), time, initial);"
the results are the following:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in Test11>ode (line 19)
dxdt(1,i) = x(6,i);

Error in Test11>@(t,x)ode(x)

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, 
varargin);

Error in Test11 (line 9)
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x)ode(x), time, initial);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `'Too many input arguments.'` is caused by the fact that your ode function only accepts one variable, `x`, while `ode45` is passing it two variables, time instance `t` and state `x`. Even if your ode equations are independent off the current time, you do need to handle this input argument.

Either let your `ode` function accept two input arguments:

```
function dxdt = ode(t,x)
% etc
```

or, change the way you call your ode function:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x)ode(x), time, initial);
```

Furthermore, I don't think `ode45` can handle a 'state matrix', so I would indeed concatenate your two state vectors vertical to one large state vector. If your don't want to rewrite your code, add some reshapes before and after the loop:

```
function [dxdt] = ode(xv)
    N = 2;
    dxdt = NaN(10,2);

    % reshape to two column vectors
    x = reshape(xv,[],2); % xv is one large column vector

    for ki = 1:N
        dxdt(1,ki) = x(6,ki);
        dxdt(6,ki) = (x(3,ki)-x(4,ki)+x(5,ki)) - x(6,ki) - x(1,ki);
        dxdt(2,ki) = x(7,ki);
        dxdt(7,ki) = (x(3,ki)-x(4,ki)+x(5,ki)) - x(7,ki) - x(2,ki);
        dxdt(3,ki) = x(8,ki);
        dxdt(8,ki) = (x(1,ki)) - x(8,ki) - x(3,ki);
        dxdt(4,ki) = x(9,ki);
        dxdt(9,ki) = (x(2,ki)) - x(9,ki) - x(4,ki);
        dxdt(5,ki) = x(10,ki);
        if ki == 1
            kj = 2;
        elseif ki == 2
            kj = 1;
        end
        dxdt(10,ki) = (x(3,kj)-x(4,kj)+x(5,kj)) - x(10,ki) - x(5,ki);
    end

    % reshape dxdt to one column vector
    dxdt = reshape(dxdt,[],1);

end
```

Comment: I did both of the first options you suggested and the error message I am receiving is:
    Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Comment: In what function/line? Please post the entire error traceback (add them to your question body by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57844689/edit) your question.